# Email issue with Custom Permission Level

Tags: 2007, list, workflow, permissions, email

I am facing a stranger issue with custom permission level in MOSS 2007. I created a custom permission level with the following access:

- Add Items
- View Items
- View Application Pages
- Open Items
- View Versions
- Create Alerts
- View Pages
- Open

I have a custom workflow which sends mail when the requester creates a new item. But with these permissions, the mail is not triggering. I do not want to allow users to Edit / delete items. Any additional permission I need to add to existing level.

Answer (score 1):

If this is an SPD workflow, then you're hitting the declarative security context issue. The workflow can't perform an action that the user can't do.

If it's a custom workflows (visual studio, then elevate the permissions in code).

Comment: I tried the scenario in my dev machine and it works fine with Read Only access also added. But same settings in PROD gives issue.

Comment: Try running WireShark on the prod server if it is possible. If the issue is clearly not permissions then there must be something else that is different. I would bet that your dev machine is using a different mail server as the relay and perhaps the declarative WF is trying to auth as the account running owstimer or something like that.